# HTTP 405 - Method Not Allowed error on a 200 OK response

Tags: java, rest, http-status-code-405

I have a small REST-ful Java back-end that some clients written in C connect to. There is a certain POST method they call where they send some information, I save that to a database and respond with 200 OK, if all goes well. Basic structure shown below.

```
@POST
@Path("/mypath")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response processMessage(final String message, @Context final HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

.....
return Response.ok().build();

}
```

My issue is that on this response, I get the following error in the log:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: No resource method found for , return 405 with Allow header
```

I understand what this error means in circumstances when let's say you try to execute a GET on an endpoint that is supposed to be a POST, for example. I can't understand though why I would get this after my response goes out, and it clearly shows that the request type is empty.... so odd.

Some additional info - the code on the client side has been buggy with incorrect HTTP code... but what would have to be wrong on the client side to cause this kind of response? (I do not have access to the client side code).

Also, there is no client side code in my app, if you are wondering if there is some other code making a call out of my webapp.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Can you post the client code?

Comment: @syrion - thanks for your quick reply, but like I mentioned above, unfortunately I do not have access to the client code.

Comment: Can you tell from a log file what's the request the client is making?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely on the client side, so without seeing that code it is difficult to offer more detailed information -- but my expectation would be that this is a result of your client attempting to do something like `POST` or `PUT` credentials, or something along that line.

Your only recourse is to enable verbose request logging, log the requests that are generating `405` errors, and report it to the client developers.

Worth noting, however, that any publicly-exposed APIs will generate piles of `405`s and `404`s because "hackers" will try to execute things like WordPress hacks and so on against any known URL.